# How to convert a line into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to convert below line into a list:

```
OK      DiskDrive       SDX  SAMSUNG MZNLN256HMHQ-000H1       SCSI\DIS...
```

My output should be like:

```
['OK', 'DiskDrive', 'SDX  SAMSUNG MZNLN256HMHQ-000H1', 'SCSI\DIS...']
```

I tried this and was not successful in getting what I wanted:

```
List = re.sub("(\w+\s{0,2}+\w)", " ", line).split()
```

Comment: You don't need regex for that. A simple `s.split()` will do the trick...

Comment: I think `s.split()` will give you `['OK', 'DiskDrive', 'SDX', 'SAMSUNG', 'MZNLN256HMHQ-000H1', 'SCSI\\DIS...']` as a list which is not the intended output. We need to have some delimiter in place to identify the split

Comment: Or use findall and list all the characters in a character class that are valid as a single match https://ideone.com/sRpcyk

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to split on more than 2 spaces in a row. For that, you can use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)'s own [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) instead of dealing with `sub`. The way to indicate *more than 2* is with `{3,}` which means *from 3 to infinity times*:

```py
import re

s = "OK      DiskDrive       SDX  SAMSUNG MZNLN256HMHQ-000H1       SCSI\DIS"

print(re.split("\s{3,}", s))
```

Gives:

```
['OK', 'DiskDrive', 'SDX  SAMSUNG MZNLN256HMHQ-000H1', 'SCSI\\DIS']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the builtin string method [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) by noting that you only want to split on those larger spaces:

```
final_list = [l.strip() for l in my_line.split('   ') if l is not '']
# ['OK', 'DiskDrive', 'SDX  SAMSUNG MZNLN256HMHQ-000H1', 'SCSI\\DIS...']
```

That `if l is not ''` just makes sure you don't end up with any empty strings in your final list.

Answer (score 0):

use findall: re pattern at least one non-whitespace, three whitespace, zero or more non whitespace characers or any character.

```
 string="OK      DiskDrive       SDX  SAMSUNG MZNLN256HMHQ-000H1       SCSI\DIS"
 pattern="([\S]+\s{0,2}[\S\w]*)"
 matches=re.findall(pattern,string)
 for match in matches:
     print(match)
```

output:

```
 OK   
 DiskDrive   
 SDX  SAMSUNG
 MZNLN256HMHQ-000H1   
 SCSI\DIS
```